# Как переименовать файл, введя новое имя с клавиатуры?

Tags: c++

У меня есть файл Total.txt
Его надо переименовать, введя новое имя с клавиатуры.
Я узнал, что переименовать файл можно с помощью функции `rename()`, но у меня не получается ввести имя самому, если только указать заранее в коде.

```
char oldname[] = "Total.txt";
char newname[] = "NewName.txt";
rename(oldname, newname);
```

Comment: *"не получается"* А как вы попробовали это сделать? Покажете код?

Comment: Такие вещи как `cin`, `getline` вам что-то говорят? `cin>>`, в крайнем случае?

Comment: Вот так пробовал:

int const nn = 10;

 char oldname[] = "Total.txt";
 char newname[nn];

 for (int i = 0; i < nn; i++)
 {
  cin >> newname[i];
 }
 rename(oldname, newname);

Comment: я пробовал через cin, например, как в прошлом моем комментарии, но имя файла получался в итоге некорректным.

Comment: решение оказалось чересчур простым, надо было немного подумать еще

Comment: @EmilNoga, вы приняли (отметили галкой) ответ, код в котором не будет компилироваться. Уверены, что это было осознанное решение?

Comment: у меня все работало, возможно я поторопился